# Gremlin Query always returns: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi, gremlinpython

Using `gremlinpython==3.7.0` per [this Azure Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin/quickstart-python), No matter what query I submit, the response is always "unhashable type: 'list'"

Unless the query results are empty, then it works fine.

Example 1 (query with no results):

```
query = f"g.V().has('label,'notareallabel')"
results = c.submit(query)
res = results.all().result()
```

returns `[]`, because there is no node with that label.

However if I run

```
query = f"g.V().has('label,'tank')"
results = c.submit(query)
res = results.all().result()
```

the results are `"unhashable type: 'list'"`. I can confirm that this query *would* run by running it in the portal:
[image]

Obviously, the returned values is a list of two object. So it wouldn't surprise me that it is a list. But Gremlinpython doesn't parse it. Is there some way to make Gremlinpython expect a list? I've already tried all variants of `values` `valuemap` and other ways to format, but because the results I want are a list, it isn't parsing them.

Comment: According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin/support) the Azure CosmosDB support for Gremlin is limited to the 3.4.13 version. Unfortunately that is a quite old client version, but perhaps try using that client.

Comment: According to this page it's 3.7.0  but I see how that could be the issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin/quickstart-python  Maybe it's just good to document the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best solution, but after much troubleshooting I found that it will work if you cast specific values, but not if you leave it open.

For example:

```
g.V().has('lable,'tank').valueMap()
```

will return `"unhashable type: 'list'"`

However:

```
g.V().has('lable,'tank').valueMap('name','display_name','description')
```

Will return values. I'm not sure why but it gives me a workaround. The bummer is that I have to know the properties of the node before I return them, which is limiting.

I think this might be more of an Azure issue than a gremlin issue. If you aren't working with Azure CosmosDB, you likely won't have this issue.

Comment: You could also try using `elementMap` but I'm not sure if that is supported on CosmosDB or not.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a simple example that could be copied and pasted?  Your Python excerpts have (label is misspelled and there's a missing quote)

```
.has('lable,'tank')
```

while your screenshot of the Azure Portal's Data Explorer has

```
.has('label','tank')
```

Using the cosmicworks db and products graph example at the referenced MS page

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin/quickstart-python

```
% python --version             
Python 3.9.16

% pip list | grep gremlinpython
gremlinpython                 3.7.1
```

(I tried 3.7.0 as well with no problem)

```
% cat app.py
import os
from gremlin_python.driver import client, serializer

ACCOUNT_NAME = os.environ["COSMOS_GREMLIN_ID"]
ACCOUNT_KEY = os.environ["COSMOS_GREMLIN_KEY"]

client = client.Client(
    url=f"wss://{ACCOUNT_NAME}.gremlin.cosmos.azure.com:443/",
    traversal_source="g",
    username="/dbs/cosmicworks/colls/products",
    password=f"{ACCOUNT_KEY}",
    message_serializer=serializer.GraphSONSerializersV2d0(),
)

query = f"g.V().has('label','product')"

results = client.submit(query)
res = results.all().result()

print(res)
```

```
% python app.py 
[{'id': '68719518371', 'label': 'product', 'type': 'vertex', 'properties': {'name': [{'id': '2cd12649-4503-439c-95ef-0619494752f7', 'value': 'Kiama classic surfboard'}], 'price': [{'id': '0ae1acbe-f361-46a5-8c7c-2e17aadc6484', 'value': 285.55}], 'category': [{'id': '68719518371|category', 'value': 'surfboards'}]}}, {'id': '68719518403', 'label': 'product', 'type': 'vertex', 'properties': {'name': [{'id': 'ca16eba3-3c9b-4ee8-b734-5660d423f643', 'value': 'Montau Turtle Surfboard'}], 'price': [{'id': 'ce8af470-8142-40bf-b14e-29d06f6dd638', 'value': 600.0}], 'category': [{'id': '68719518403|category', 'value': 'surfboards'}]}}, {'id': '68719518409', 'label': 'product', 'type': 'vertex', 'properties': {'name': [{'id': '43d20d34-7271-4e2f-be57-a85e8fa85889', 'value': 'Bondi Twin Surfboard'}], 'price': [{'id': 'd8e48c98-5606-4d6e-a059-fb8fd34d3266', 'value': 585.5}], 'category': [{'id': '68719518409|category', 'value': 'surfboards'}]}}]
```

Comment: Note that you are referencing the same doc as me. No it's not the spelling (I mispelled it in my example, and updated) You can see in the image that the 'label' is correct. That's interesting that you get different results. I'm keeping this here in case anyone else comes up with the same issue.